# apex:page recordsetVar query

Tags: visualforce, controller

I know that mentioning "recordsetVar" attribute in conjunction with standardcontroller  in apex:page component will make it as a standard set controller.

Can you someone let know how that collection is intialized and with what values ?

Does it by default pulls all the records from that object ?

Comment: Its gone be standard list controller i believe not set controller

Answer (score 1):

From VF component reference :

> "This attribute indicates that the page uses a set-oriented standard
>   controller."

By default, salesforce creates a StandardSetController from this objects records. This is initialised by a random query and any of the first 10k records will be selected.

Also, you can perform additional operations on StandardSetController in Apex class and can apply filters (List view etc.).

More details on StandardSetController

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm